# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado &apos;Microsoft.Web.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0

Tags: unity3d

Acabo de instalar [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d) en su versión `5.3.1f1`.
Posteriormente importé un proyecto que tenía de un `Unity3D 3.4` y al abrir un código de [unityscript](/questions/tagged/unityscript) en el [visualstudio](/questions/tagged/visualstudio) que trae me sale una ventana indicándome que se produjo un error y que consulte el log.

[image: mensaje de error]

Al revisar el log me encuentro lo siguiente:

```
<source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el
     archivo o ensamblado &apos;Microsoft.Web.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0,
     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; ni una de sus
     dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo 
     especificado.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.Web.Editor,
     Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;  
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.VsPackage.WpfTextViewConnectionListener.SubjectBuffersConnected(IWpfTextView textView, ConnectionReason reason, Collection`1 subjectBuffers)&#x000D;&#x000A; 
     at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.ConnectionManager.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4_1.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A; 

     at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object errorSource, Action call)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;AVS:
 El registro del enlace de ensamblado est&#x00E1; 
     desactivado.&#x000D;&#x000A;Para habilitar el registro de errores 
     del enlace de ensamblado, establezca el valor de Registro 
     [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) como 
     1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Nota: existe una disminuci&#x00F3;n del 
     rendimiento asociada registro de errores del enlace de 
     ensamblado.&#x000D;&#x000A;Para desactivar esta 
     caracter&#x00ED;stica, elimine el valor de Registro 
     [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;
 </description>
```

¿Alguien sabe de donde consigo ese Microsoft Web Editor o que tengo que hacer para que deje de marcar error?

Comment: quizas este error este relacionado con el -> Error CS1061 'Mesh'... que usted posteo, solo es un comentario pues no uso VS, quizas ayude Saludos

Comment: No lo está, el otro error ya lo resolví, gracias. Lo que noto aquí es que me abrió un javascript en un proyecto C#... eso debería de bastar para explicar el error, pero igual no entiendo como se deben abrir los javascript en el vs :)

Comment: ¿cómo resolviste este problema?